# Show report in iframe with http.get() call

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I'm trying to load a report with an `http.get()` call and show it in an `iframe` using angularJS 2.0.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="report-viewer">
    <button (click)="loadReport()">Call API!</button>
    <iframe src="report"></iframe>
</div>
```

- Klick on button calls a function in my controller, where I call the API with an `http.get()`

My controller looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-report-viewer',
    templateUrl: './report-viewer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./report-viewer.component.scss']
})
export class ReportViewerComponent implements OnInit {

    report: Observable<any>;
    reportUrl: "http://localhost:47503/reports/html";

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    loadReport() {
        this.http.get(this.reportUrl).map(repsonse => this.report);
    }
}
```

- I try to call the API and put my response in my variable `report`. After that, on the iframe in my HTML I try to show the response like this: `<iframe src="report"></iframe>`

The problem I have is, that my API call doesn't work, when I click on the `button`. There are no errors in the console, no traffic. I also set a breakpoint in my backend, but it doesn't come throught. It also duplicates my buttons and iframes within (look at screenshot). When I change it like this, it showes me the HTML of my report within my `iframe`: `<iframe src="http://localhost:47503/reports/html"></iframe>`. So when I put the link directly in the `src` of the `iframe`, I got some data (html, css) and also my breakpoint in the backend works (look at screenshot). So whats wrong or whats the difference? Any idea?

Call function from controller:
[image]

Call link directly in src of iframe:
[image]

Comment: Does you loadReport function get called?

Comment: Also instead of using src, use srcdoc attribute to display the document. Other way is to write the response in the iframe document using iframe..document.write(your response)

Comment: @gusaindpk I put a console.log() in it - it shows me the right output in the console so the function works.

Comment: if you are getting the response in your js code you can write the response to iframe using  iframe..document.write(your response). instead of setting it in the html vai angular binding. let kwon if it helps

Comment: @gusaindpk As you can see, the problem I have actually is, that I can't call the API with my http.get() call, so there also can't be a response... Is there an error in my call or something? My breakpoint doesn't catch the call by clicking on the button and calling my loadReport() function... The breakpoint only works, if I call the URL directly in the src of my iframe...

Comment: Can you look in the example http://devdocs.io/angular~2_typescript/api/http/index/http-class. I think we have to use .subscribe to attach the response to the report object. http://devdocs.io/angular~2_typescript/api/http/index/http-class

Comment: @gusaindpk I get this message in my console when I hit the button: "Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode."

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-report-viewer',
    templateUrl: './report-viewer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./report-viewer.component.scss']
})
export class ReportViewerComponent implements OnInit {

    report: Observable<any>;
    reportUrl: "http://localhost:47503/reports/html";

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    loadReport() {
        this.report = this.http.get(this.reportUrl)
    }
}
```